# How to have a view returned for each id?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to return view where Task Created will have each user assigned to them. 
Example

In my view blade, I click on Task Name -> it should return a view of task assign under task id 1 to add users to work on the task 
Task Controller

```
    public function show($id)
{
    $task = Task::find($id); 
    $task->task_assignments = TaskAssignment::where('task_id', $task->id)->get();

    return view('tAssignments.index')->with('task', $task); 
}
```

Task Assignment Controller

```
   public function show($id)
{   
    $task = Task::find($id); 
    $task_assignments = TaskAssignment::find($id); 
    return view('tAssignments.index', compact('task', 'task_assignments')); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fetch the data for that user about whom you want to know 
Use
->findOrFail(id)
Return that data in the view file and render it according to use.
If you want it more perfectly you may use a ajax call .

Answer (score 0):

This is how i manage to answer and pass the variable. Please let me know if there is any better view

```
public function show($id)
{    
    $task = Task::findOrFail($id); 
    $task_assignment = TaskAssignment::find($id);
    $task->task_assignments = TaskAssignment::where('task_id', $task->id)->get();
    return view('tAssignments.index', compact('task', 'task_assignment'))->with('task_id', $task->id); 
}
```